# How do I set up Emacs on Linux to read/send mail from Gmail?

Tags: email, emacs

I generally like Gmail, but there's something about well formatted, color highlighted plain text over a black background that appeals to me a lot. I'd like to be able to use Emacs to read/send email using my Gmail account, but setting it up is infuriatingly difficult. I tried a bunch of extensions and tutorials, but none of them gave me a fully working email setup for Emacs.

This is going to be my last try before I give up. I'm on Ubuntu 11.10, standard Unity shell, using Emacs 23.3. Please tell me once and for all how to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnus seems to have some [instructions](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/GnusGmail) for GMail. Using IMAP is probably best since it leaves mail accessible with other clients and the web interface if something goes wrong locally.

Answer (score 2):

I use offlineimap + dovecot for having the mails localy.

My .offlineimaprc is:

```
[general]
accounts = Locals, Gmail
maxsyncaccounts = 2

[Account Gmail]
localrepository = Local
remoterepository = Remote
autorefresh = 5

[Repository Local]
type = Maildir
localfolders = ~/Maildir

[Repository Remote]
type = Gmail
remotehost = imap.gmail.com
remoteuser = my.email@gmail.com
```

My /etc/dovecot.conf contain:

```
default_mail_env = maildir:%h/Maildir
```

and my .gnus have:

```
(setq imap-shell-program "/usr/lib/dovecot/imap")

(setq gnus-secondary-select-methods
      '((nndraft "")
        (nnimap "localhost"
         (nnimap-stream shell)))))
```

For outgoing mail I use:

```
(setq send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it)
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it)
(setq smtpmail-starttls-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 nil nil)))
(setq smtpmail-auth-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 "my.email@gmail.com" nil)))
(setq smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com")
(setq smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com")
(setq smtpmail-smtp-service 587)
```

And it just work.

Comment: I installed dovecot and it warned me that its "conf file does not belong to the current user". Not sure what to do with this. Also, I couldn't find the imap shell program. There's no imap file in /usr/lib/dovecot

Comment: I don't know how you installed dovecot. I use Debian, and the dovecot package from debian unstable (package dovecot-imapd)

Answer (score 0):

wl does the job too

Wanderlust http://www.gohome.org/wl/